# Provider Error when using MembershipCreateStatus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I searched in stack overflow for this problem and try some of them but it does not solve, My project was working fine yesterday but today when i want to register a new user i get Provider Error!!
this is my register method in Account Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        var _userdata = new UsersDataAccess();
        var _u = _userdata.FindUser(model.UserName);
        if (_u)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", " کد کاربری قبلا استفاده شده است.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var samaMembershipProvider = Membership.Provider as SamaMembershipProvider;
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = new MembershipCreateStatus();
                if (model.ConfirmPassword==model.Password)
                {
              samaMembershipProvider.CreateUser(
                        model.UserName,
                        model.Password,
                        model.Email,
                        true,
                        model.FirstName,
                        model.LastName,
                        model.gender,
                        model.Mobile,
                        new string[] { RoleEnum.Users.ToString() },
                         out createStatus
                        );
                    switch (createStatus)
                    {
                        case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);
                            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

                        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", " آدرس ایمیل قبلا در سامانه ثبت شده است");
                            break;
                        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "  کد کاربری قبلا در سامانه ثبت شده است");
                            break;
                        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                            ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "کلمه عبور وارد شده معتبر نیست");
                            break;
                        //case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                        //    TempData["Alert"] = " خطا در ذخیره اطلاعات " + " نقش دانشجو وجود ندارد " + "مجددا تلاش کنید. در صورتی که موفق نشدید با مدیر سیستم تماس بگیرید";
                        //    break;

                        default:
                            TempData["Alert"] = " خطا در ذخیره اطلاعات " + createStatus.ToString();
                            break;
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmPassword","کلمه عبور و تکرار کلمه عبور با هم برابر نیستند");
                }



            }
        }


        return View();

    }
```

but at samaMembershipProvider.CreateUser the  createStatus return providererror.

and this is the only method that i change in MembershipProvider

```
//CreateUser by Golnaz
    public  MembershipUser CreateUser
       (string username, string password, string email, bool isApproved, string FirstName, string LastName,
        int gender, string Mobile, string[] Role, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        ValidatePasswordEventArgs args = new ValidatePasswordEventArgs(username, password, true);

        OnValidatingPassword(args);

        if (args.Cancel)
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
            return null;
        }

        if (RequiresUniqueEmail && GetUserNameByEmail(email) != "")
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
            return null;
        }

            DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now;
            int rowsAffected = 0;
            //int rowsAffected1 = 0; // GOLNAZ

            User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
                return null;
            }

            user = new User();
            user.UserName = username;
            user.Password = EncodePassword(password);
            user.PasswordSalt = "";
            user.Email = email;
            user.PasswordQuestion = null;
            user.PasswordAnswer = null;
            user.IsApproved = isApproved;
            user.IsLockedOut = false;
            user.LastActivityDate = createDate;
            user.CreateDate = createDate;
            user.LastLoginDate = createDate;
            user.LastLockedOutDate = createDate;
            user.LastPasswordChangedDate = createDate;
            user.FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0;
            user.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = createDate;
            user.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0;
            user.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = createDate;
            user.Comment = "";

            //GOLNAZ
            user.Person = new Person();
            user.Person.FirstName = FirstName;
            user.Person.LastName = LastName;
            user.Person.GenderId = gender;
            user.Person.CellPhoneNumber = Mobile;

            //GOLNAZ

            foreach (var roleName in Role)
            {

                var role = db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoleName == roleName);

                if (role == null)
                {
                    // return invalid answer for invalid role
                    status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer;
                    return null;
                }

                user.Roles.Add(role);
            }



            try
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);//AddToUsers(user);
                rowsAffected = db.SaveChanges();

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                    status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
                else
                    status = MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;

                if (WriteExceptionsToEventLog)
                    WriteToEventLog(ex, "CreateUser");
            }



            return GetUser(username, false);
        }
```

when I run my project and fill the registration form in my view by using the break points in account controller this is what i see

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osVX1.png)

Comment: It is hard to tell what error has thrown on your code right now, show the error message including exception details (inner exception, stack trace etc).

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto i didn't get any error or exception but because the out of CreateUser is provide error the registration didn't save in data base

Comment: I will add a picture of that